# How do I serialize an enum to a number and deserialize from a number via serde-json?

Tags: json, rust, serde

```
struct ResponseData<T> {
    success : bool,
    res_data : T,
}
struct FooRes {
   result:RESULT,
}
num RESULT {
    RESULT_OK = 0,
    RESULT_NG = 1,
}
fn test(){

let s = ResponseData::<FooRes>{
    success : true,
    res_data : FooRes{
        result:RESULT::RESULT_OK,
    },
};
    
let st = serde_json::to_string(&s).unwrap();
println!("json={}",st);
```

json={"success":true,"resData":{"result":"RESULT_OK"}}

I need the outcome to be `{"result":0}`, not `{"result":"RESULT_OK"}`, when serializing the enum into a number value,
and `{"success":true,"resData":{"result":0}}` to deserialize to the enum member `result`.

```
struct FooRes {
   result:RESULT,
}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some extra time to ensure that your question contains a [mre], and that the question is clear and well presented ([ask]). That code is poorly formatted and does not even compile.

Comment: The serde homepage on [Enum representations](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html) might give you an idea on how to work with enum types in serde.

Answer (score 1):

Thunks, I solved

https://serde.rs/enum-number.html

Correct
#[derive(Serialize_repr, Deserialize_repr, PartialEq, Debug)]
Not
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]

On Enum , tnx